How can the satisfaction relation for models relate multiple structures to a sentence/theory?
I am reading H.-D. Ebbinghaus's "Extended Logics: The General Framework" in Barwise and Feferman, Model-Theoretic Logics. Proposition 5.1.2 of that chapter mentions a claim involving model-theoretic satisfaction that I can't make sense of. It appears to say that a structure and the denotation of a term satisfy a theory, but I don't understand what this could mean.
In more detail, the following paraphrases the relevant proposition:

Assume $\mathcal{L}$ is a compact logic, $\tau $ a signature and $\phi \in \mathcal{L}[\tau]$. Take a renaming $\rho: \tau \mapsto \tau^{\prime}$ where $\tau $ and $\tau^{\prime}$ are disjoint. Set:


$\Phi = \{ \forall x (Rx \leftrightarrow \rho (R)x \mid R \in \tau) \} \cup \{ \forall x f(x) = \rho(f)(x) \mid f \in \tau \} \cup  \{ c = \rho (c) \mid c \in \tau \}$


$\Phi \models \phi \leftrightarrow \phi^{\rho}$. Since $\mathcal{L}$ is compact, there is a finite $\Phi_0 \subset \Phi $ such that $\Phi \models \phi \leftrightarrow \phi^{\rho}$. Let $\tau_0$ be the set of symbols occurring in $\Phi_0$. If $\frak{U}, \frak{B}$ are $\tau$-structures, with $\frak{U}\upharpoonright \tau_0 \cong \frak{B}\upharpoonright \tau_0$ we have $(\frak{U}, (\rho (\sigma)^{\frak{B}^{\rho}})_{\sigma \in \tau}) \models \Phi_0 $ and therefore $\frak{U} \models \phi $ iff $\frak{B}^{\rho} \models \phi^{\rho} $ iff $\frak{B} \models \phi $.

It is the last few clauses I don't follow. What does it mean that $(\frak{U}, (\rho (\sigma)^{\frak{B}^{\rho}})_{\sigma \in \tau}) \models \Phi_0 $ ? $\frak{U} $ can't satisfy $\Phi_0$ alone since it is in the wrong signature.
Is $(\frak{U}, (\rho (\sigma)^{\frak{B}^{\rho}})_{\sigma \in \tau})$ a way of expanding $\frak{U}$ so it will be in the right signature?
And if so, what is $(\rho (\sigma)^{\frak{B}^{\rho}})_{\sigma \in \tau}$?
I want to say it is the set of things denoted by the renamings of terms in $\tau$ in the $\rho$-renaming of $\frak{B}$, but I can't really make sense of it.

See Remark page 28 about renaming. Silly example with $\tau = { \in }$ and $\tau' = { \lt }$, i.e. two languages with only a binary relation symbol each. Then $\rho (\in)= \lt$. Thus, if $\varphi$ is a formula in the first vocabulary, $\varphi^{\rho}$ is the result of rewriting the formula with $\lt$ in place of $\in$.

If so, every structure $A$ for $\tau$ produces a corresponding structure $A^{ \rho }$ for $\tau'$.

I think I understand this. What confuses me is just expressions like $(\frak{U}, a) \models \phi $. $\models $ ' is a relation between structures and sentences, so what is $a$ ' doing?

Ok, thank you I think I understand now! Essentially, the claim is that a modification of the structure $\frak{U}$ models the relevant formula.

See Remark page 28 about renaming.
Silly example with $τ = \{ ∈ \}$ and $τ′= \{ < \}$ , i.e. two languages with only a binary relation symbol each.
Then $ρ(∈)=<$ and thus, if $\phi$  is a formula in the first vocabulary, $\phi^ρ$
is the result of rewriting the formula with <  in place of ∈.
Every structure $A$ for $τ$  produces a corresponding structure $A^ρ$  for $τ′$.
Using this example where $σ∈τ$ is simply $\in$ and $ρ(∈)$ is $<$, $B^ρ$  is the structure for the language with $<$ in place of $∈$. Thus, $(A,ρ(σ)^B)$ is the structure $A$  "translated" to fit the language $ρ(τ)$.
